# How to create gradient at corner container flutter?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8val.png) how to create a gradient at both left and right corner in the container like in the image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/echvR.png) This is what I expected like in the image. Anyone can help with that? Really appreciate that.

Comment: Use Box Decoration with Gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean at both left and right both sides of the container try this code:

```
class GradientContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientContainer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
      width: 500.0,
      height: 40.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          stops: [0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0],
          colors: [
            Color(0xfff9c31d).withOpacity(0.02),
            Color(0xfff9c31d),
            Color(0xfff9c31d),
            Color(0xfff9c31d),
            Color(0xfff9c31d),
            Color(0xfff9c31d),
            Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.02),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hello, Gradient!',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can customize the rest of the necessary changes by changing the numbers and attributes